# Z3 Optimizer Unsatisfiability with Real Constraints Using C++ API

Tags: c++, optimization, z3

I'm running into a problem when trying to use the Z3 optimizer to solve graph partitioning problems.  Specifically, the code bellow will fail to produce a satisfying model:

```
namespace z3 {
    expr ite(context& con, expr cond, expr then_, expr else_) {
        return to_expr(con, Z3_mk_ite(con, cond, then_, else_));;
    }
}

bool smtPart(void) {

    // Graph setup

    vector<int32_t> nodes = {{ 4, 2, 1, 1 }};
    vector<tuple<node_pos_t, node_pos_t, int32_t>> edges;
    GraphType graph(nodes, edges);

    // Z3 setup
    z3::context con;
    z3::optimize opt(con);
    string n_str = "n", sub_p_str = "_p";

    // Re-usable constants
    z3::expr zero = con.int_val(0);

    // Create the sort representing the different partitions.

    const char* part_sort_names[2] = { "P0", "P1" };
    z3::func_decl_vector part_consts(con), part_preds(con);

    z3::sort part_sort =
        con.enumeration_sort("PartID",
                             2,
                             part_sort_names,
                             part_consts,
                             part_preds);

    // Create the constants that represent partition choices.

    vector<z3::expr> part_vars;
    part_vars.reserve(graph.numNodes());

    z3::expr p0_acc = zero,
             p1_acc = zero;

    typename GraphType::NodeData total_weight = typename GraphType::NodeData();
    for (const auto& node : graph.nodes()) {
        total_weight += node.data;

        ostringstream name;
        name << n_str << node.id << sub_p_str;

        z3::expr nchoice = con.constant(name.str().c_str(), part_sort);
        part_vars.push_back(nchoice);

        p0_acc = p0_acc + z3::ite(con,
                                  nchoice == part_consts[0](), 
                                  con.int_val(node.data),
                                  zero);

        p1_acc = p1_acc + z3::ite(con,
                                  nchoice == part_consts[1](),
                                  con.int_val(node.data),
                                  zero);
    }

    z3::expr imbalance = con.int_const("imbalance");
    opt.add(imbalance ==
            z3::ite(con,
                    p0_acc > p1_acc,
                    p0_acc - p1_acc,
                    p1_acc - p0_acc));

    z3::expr imbalance_limit = con.real_val(total_weight, 100);
    opt.add(imbalance <= imbalance_limit);

    z3::expr edge_cut = zero;
    for(const auto& edge : graph.edges()) {
        edge_cut = edge_cut +
                   z3::ite(con,
                           (part_vars[edge.node0().pos()] ==
                              part_vars[edge.node1().pos()]),
                           zero,
                           con.int_val(edge.data));
    }

    opt.minimize(edge_cut);
    opt.minimize(imbalance);

    z3::check_result opt_result = opt.check();

    if (opt_result == z3::check_result::sat) {
        auto mod = opt.get_model();

        size_t node_id = 0;
        for (z3::expr& npv : part_vars) {
            cout << "Node " << node_id++ << ": " << mod.eval(npv) << endl;
        }

        return true;
    } else if (opt_result == z3::check_result::unsat) {
        cerr << "Constraints are unsatisfiable." << endl;
        return false;
    } else {
        cerr << "Result is unknown." << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

If I remove the `minimize` commands and use a `solver` instead of an `optimize` it will find a satisfying model with 0 imbalance.  I can also get an `optimize` to find a satisfying model if I either:

1. Remove the constraint `imbalance <= imbalance_limit` or
2. Make the imbalance limit reducible to an integer.  In this example the total weight is 8.  If the imbalance limit is set to 8/1, 8/2, 8/4, or 8/8 the optimizer will find satisfying models.

I have tried `to_real(imbalance) <= imbalance_limit` to no avail.  I also considered the possibility that Z3 is using the wrong logic (one that doesn't include theories for real numbers) but I haven't found a way to set that using the C/C++ API.

If anyone could tell me why the optimizer fails in the presence of the real valued constraint or could suggest improvements to my encoding it would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having trouble compiling your code.  What #include directives are you using?  What namespace?  What compiler and linker flags?

Comment: I only really intended for this code to be read, not compiled.  This is part of a much larger project that defines a bunch of the stuff used here.  Thanks for taking the time to look into this, but it turns out this was a bug.  Please see my answer below for more details.

Comment: OK, nice work on finding a bug in Z3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was a bug in Z3.  I created an [Issue](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/683) on GitHub and they have since responded with a patch.  I'm compiling and testing the fix now, but I expect it to work.

Edit:  Yup, that patch fixed the issue for the command line tool and the C++ API.

Answer (score 0):

Could you reproduce the result by using opt.to_string() to dump the state (just before the check())? This would create a string formatted in SMT-LIB2 with optimization commands. It is then easier to exchange benchmarks. You should see that it reports unsat with the optimization commands and sat if you comment out the optimization commands.

If you are able to produce a bug, then post an issue on GitHub.com/z3prover/z3.git with a repro.

If not, you can use Z3_open_log before you create the z3 context and record a rerunnable log file. It is possible (but not as easy) to dig into unsoundness bugs that way.

Comment: Thanks for the information about printing out `opt`.  I tried specifying different logics via the Z3 command line tool but that didn't solve anything.  I was able to reproduce the same behavior in the command line too though, and have now submitted an issue to the GitHub page.